# How do I make shelve file empty in python?

Tags: python, shelve

I have created a shelve file and inserted a dictionary data. Now I want to cleanup that shelve file to reuse as a clean file.

```
import shelve
dict = shelve.open("Sample.db")
# insert some data into sample.db
dict = { "foo" : "bar"}

#Now I want to clean entire shelve file to re-insert the data from begining.
```

Comment: Why not just delete the file?

Comment: Note that `dict = { "foo" : "bar"}` should be `dict["foo"] = "bar"`. As it is now, it doesn't insert data into the shelf object - instead it points `dict` to a new dictionary object while leaving the shelf unchanged.

Answer (score 17):

Shelve behaves just like a dictionary, thus:

```
dict.clear()
```

Alternatively, you can always remove the file and let shelve create a new one.

Comment: The `shelve` module is allowed to add stuff to the filename you give it, and on my machine it actually creates a couple files. Clearing the dictionary seems easier as it steers clear of the question of what file or files to delete.

Comment: The most simplest explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`dict.clear()` is the easiest, and should be valid, but seems to not actually clear the shelf files (Python 3.5.2, Windows 7 64-bit). For example, the shelf `.dat` file size grows every time I run the following snippet, while I would expect it to always have the same size:

```
shelf = shelve.open('shelf')
shelf.clear()
shelf['0'] = list(range(10000))
shelf.close()
```

---

**Update:** `dbm.dumb`, which `shelve` uses as its underlying database under Windows, contains this TODO item [in its code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dbm/dumb.py):

> - reclaim free space (currently, space once occupied by deleted or expanded items is never reused)

This explains the ever-growing shelf file problem.

---

So instead of `dict.clear()`, I'm using `shelve.open` with `flag='n'`. Quoting [`shelve.open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.open):

> The optional flag parameter has the same interpretation as the flag
>   parameter of dbm.open().

And [`dbm.open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#dbm.open) for `flag='n'`:

> Always create a new, empty database, open for reading and writing

If the shelf is already open, the usage would be:

```
shelf.close()
shelf = shelve.open('shelf', flag='n')
```

Comment: 6 1/2  years later and this is still the best way.

Answer (score 1):

none of these really work What I ended up doing was creating a function to handle the file deletion.

```
import shelve
import pyperclip
import sys
import os

mcbShelf = shelve.open('mcb')
command = sys.argv[1].lower()

def remove_files():
    mcbShelf.close()
    os.remove('mcb.dat')
    os.remove('mcb.bak')
    os.remove('mcb.dir')

if command == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif command == 'list':
    pyperclip.copy(", ".join(mcbShelf.keys()))
elif command == 'del':
    remove_files()
else:
    pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

Comment: This would have worked as well:     # Delete all keywords (key in the mcbShelf)
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() == 'delete':
        for keyword in list(mcbShelf.keys()):
            del mcbShelf[keyword]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
if os.path.isfile(mcbShelf):
   os.remove(mcbShelf)
```

Comment: remove file or empty the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a for loop to remove content from shelf:

```
for key in shelf.keys():
            del shelf[key]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
del dict["foo"]
```