# How to clean a Python shelf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, data-storage, shelve

I have a python shelf file that's roughly 100MB in size.
I have a naive function that's supposed to clean the shelf from unneeded entries that looks like this:

```
def cleanShelf(shelf):
    for key in shelf:
        if not stillNeeded(shelf[key]):
            del shelf[key]
```

But this function only processes roughly 2 entries per second and my shelf file currently has over 100'000 entries.
Same goes for `shelf.clear()`, it's incredibly slow and doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any efficient way of maintaining a shelf file?

Comment: **Not** an answer to your question, but interesting read nevertheless: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341411/how-do-i-make-shelve-file-empty-in-python

Comment: It may be faster to simply add the entries you *do* need to a new shelf, then replace the original file with your new file.

Comment: instead of `del shelf[key]` try `shelf.__delitem__(key)`, i am not sure but it might be faster